# to batch trace (vectorize) many bitmaps to .swf?

Tags: batch-file, bitmap, adobe, flash

Does anybody know way to batch trace (vectorize) many bitmaps into flash .swf format on the fly?

I could do it with Flash Pro, but i am looking for tracing big numbers of them so need automated way to do it.

there are some batch tracing progs for svg, but i need to trace into .swf

(p.s. I now there are tools to embed bitmap into swf , I actually need to trace them)

thanks

Comment: best would be command line tool, ( tried AutoTrace but seems not to trace into swf)

Comment: If using the flash ide works, how about writing a jsfl script to automate doing it many times?

Answer (score 1):

- You could trace the images directly from AS3 using the
  [as3potrace](https://github.com/PowerflasherBR/as3potrace) library & save it. A minimal code for tracing can be
  found [here](http://wahlers.com.br/claus/blog/as3-bitmap-tracer-vectorizer-as3potrace/). Another project is the [vectorizationpackage](http://code.google.com/p/vectorizationpackage/downloads/list).
- Use a console script to modify the image path in the as3 code &
  recompile for multiple images. To recompile from command line, you
  would need to use [JSFL](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2004/08/jsfl_fla_batch.html) as suggested by *mitim*.